# Turn led ON using PWM on TM4C123

Tags: c++, c, pwm

I am looking for help with TM4C123 PWM code. I want to adjust the PWM with 0 and 100% duty cycle with the 2 buttons. It will be if I press 1 switch the PWM signal should be 100% and the led should glow, as soon as I press the another switch the duty cycle should be 0% and the switch should be off. Basically I am looking for an ON/OFF switch using PWM.
All the help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done? If you want 100% duty cycle, you turn the output ON and if you want 0% you turn it OFF. It is like saying: 'These goods have to stay in the yard and I need a semi trailer to do it.'

Comment: As Vane points out, there is no reason to utilize a PWM for what you are describing. I think you need to evaluate on what you are trying to achieve and how you are going about it, if it were me. I would look at the buttons, do I need an interrupt, do I need them software debounced? Are they active high/low etc. Then look at do I need the output to be modulated ? If yes look into a timer in PWM mode and specify my configuration, should it be and LED then 100 Hz is sufficient, should it be variable duty cycle? and then configure the timer - there is a lot of material available for TI launchpads.

Comment: Also think about - Do you want to do it the hard way and go the bare metal route and dig through the 1200+ pages datasheet or should you look at a library for that specific board/mcu you using - such as TivaWare https://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C